# Executing Mahout against Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, mahout

I have a jar file which contains the mahout jars as well as other code I wrote.
It works fine in my local machine.
I would like to run it in a cluster that has Hadoop already installed.

When I do

$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar myjar.jar args

I get the error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create /some/hdfs/path (exists=false, cwd=file:local/folder/where/myjar/is)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java 440)
...
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

I checked that I can access and create the dir in the hdfs system.
I have also ran hadoop code (no mahout) without a problem.

I am running this in a linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the mahout user and hadoop user being same. and also check for mahout and hadoop version compatibility.

Regards
Jyoti ranjan panda